# Reverse Java Graphics2D scaled and rotated coordinates

Tags: java, graphics, coordinates, reverse

I use Graphics2D in Java to scale and rotate the picture I draw. I now want to be able to tell what the original coordinates were when I click on a certain point in the picture. So given the rotated and scaled coordinates I want to calculate the original ones. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821381/cant-get-my-coordinates-graphics2d-mouseclick-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you keep a copy of the `AffineTransform` you use when you paint the image, you can use
 [AffineTransform.inverseTransform(Point2D ptSrc, Point2D ptDst)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#inverseTransform%28java.awt.geom.Point2D,%20java.awt.geom.Point2D%29)
to transform a device space coordinate back to user space

**Edit**: If you capture the current transform of the `Graphics2D` while painting, beware of the `Graphics2D` being re-used for multiple lightweight children of the same window/panel, because then the transform will be relative to the parent component but the mouse coordinates will be relative to the child.  You need to capture the *changes* you make to the transform not its final value.  Example:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.NoninvertibleTransformException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png"));
        AffineTransform xfrm1 = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(0.95, 1.25);
        xfrm1.rotate(-0.3);
        box.add(new ImageView(image, xfrm1));
        AffineTransform xfrm2 = AffineTransform.getShearInstance(0.1, 0.2);
        xfrm2.scale(1.3, 0.9);
        box.add(new ImageView(image, xfrm2));
        frame.add(box);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ImageView extends JComponent {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        try {
            paintXfrm = g2d.getTransform();
            paintXfrm.invert();
            g2d.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
            g2d.transform(xfrm);
            g2d.translate(image.getWidth() * -0.5, image.getHeight() * -0.5);
            paintXfrm.concatenate(g2d.getTransform());
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        } catch (NoninvertibleTransformException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(image.getWidth() * 2, image.getHeight() * 2);
    }

    ImageView(final BufferedImage image, final AffineTransform xfrm) {
        this.canvas = image.createGraphics();
        canvas.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
        this.image = image;
        this.xfrm = xfrm;
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                try {
                    mouseDownCoord = e.getPoint();
                    paintXfrm.inverseTransform(mouseDownCoord, mouseDownCoord);
                } catch (NoninvertibleTransformException ex) {
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                mouseDownCoord = null;
            }
        });
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Point p = e.getPoint();
                try {
                    paintXfrm.inverseTransform(p, p);
                    if (mouseDownCoord != null) {
                        canvas.drawLine(mouseDownCoord.x, mouseDownCoord.y, p.x, p.y);
                        for (Component sibling: getParent().getComponents()) {
                            sibling.repaint();
                        }
                    }
                    mouseDownCoord = p;
                } catch (NoninvertibleTransformException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Graphics2D canvas;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private AffineTransform xfrm;
    private AffineTransform paintXfrm;
    private Point mouseDownCoord;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear exactly how you're rotating and scaling. But you're probably using an [AffineTransform](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html). Fortunately, there's a [createInverse()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createInverse()) method and a [inverseTransform()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#inverseTransform(java.awt.geom.Point2D,%20java.awt.geom.Point2D)) method.

So your code might be

```
AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.rotate(theta);
transform.scale(sx, sy);
```

Then to invert, you can say

```
Point2D pointInOrigCoords = transform.inverseTransform(clickPoint,null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not so hard ;-)

1. When you repaint the Component save the `AffineTransform` after the transforming with `g2.getTransform()`
2. Then call the function `invert()` on it
3. In the `mouseClicked()` event us the following code:

   ```
   Point2D p= trans.transform(new Point2D.Double(evt.getX(), evt.getY()), null);
   System.out.println("click x="+p.getX()+" y="+p.getY());
   ```

Thats it!