# non-destructive transformations on java2d objects

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I would like to be able to zoom and unzoom on a Java2D scene made of Path2D.Double without
thickening the lines, just by dilating the distances.

I'v tried to apply a transformation to the Graphics2D object the paintComponent method receives, but this makes the lines thicker. The only way I found was to apply a transformation to the lines (`line.transform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(2d,2d))` for instance) but every time I zoom and unzoom again, I lose information because of floating point errors.

To make a long story short: the transformations are destructive. is there a way to say "i want to draw this line with that transformation applied without modifying the content of the line"?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: I change the line width according to the scale factor in Graphic2D, that way I  can apply the transform to Graphic2D itself and it doesn't destruct the original coordinates contained in the Path2D.

```
tr = g.getTransform()
g.transform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scaleFactor,scaleFactor))
g.setStroke(new java.awt.BasicStroke(1.0f/scaleFactor.toFloat))
/* draw lines */
g.setTransform(tr)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you found, changing the [`Graphics2D`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) transform affects *all* drawing, but nothing precludes saving, modifying and restoring the transform inside `paintComponent()`. In this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/scaledview), the content is drawn in a scaled context, while a `Rectangle.Double` surrounding the target object is drawn unscaled.

Addendum: The [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/scaledview) uses explicit transformations, but you can use `AffineTransform`, instead. Like `Rectangle2D`, `Path2D` implements the `Shape` interface, so you can use [`createInverse()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createInverse%28%29) and [`createTransformedShape()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape%28java.awt.Shape%29), accordingly. Here's a related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244157).

Comment: I saw that I could save a transformation and restore it later for what concerns Graphics2D but I what I would like to do can be reformulated as doing the same with a Path2D.

Comment: @Paul Brauner: You can use `AffineTransform` on `Path2D`, as suggested above.

Comment: yep, but then it modifies the Path2D, that's the whole point, I would like to be able to apply it to a Path2D and get a new one without modifying the original one

Comment: @Paul Brauner: I'd think you could use the copy constructor, `Path2D.Double(Shape s, AffineTransform at)`, to copy and transform the original.