# Java BufferedImage padding

Tags: java, java-2d, bufferedimage

Is there any faster way to achieve padding of pixels to a BufferedImage than drawing it centered on larger BufferedImage?

Comment: is the padding just for display purposes or do you need to create a new padded image?

Comment: this is mostly for generating a new padded image, not just rendering it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BufferedImage has a constructor where you get to specify a WriteableRaster.

Picking at the a default buffered image, storing each pixel in an int, it uses an IntegerInterleavedRaster.

The ColorModel you can use ColorModel.getRGBDefault().

```
int imageWidth = 638, imageHeight = 480;
int dataImageWidth = 640;

SampleModel sm = new SinglePixelPackedSampleModel(TYPE_INT, imageWidth, imageHeight, dataImageWidth, new int[] { 0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff });
DataBuffer db = new DataBufferInt(dataImageWidth * imageHeight);
WritableRaster r = Raster.createWritableRaster(sm, db, new Point());
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(ColorModel.getRGBDefault(), r, false, null);
```

Notice the scanlineStride in SinglePixelPackedSampleModel (second last parameter).

Another much simpler approach is to use BufferedImage's getSubimage method.

```
BufferedImage fullImage = new BufferedImage(dataImageWidth, imageHeight);
BufferedImage subImage = fullImage.getSubimage(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an ImageIcon using the BufferedImage and add the Icon to a JLabel. Then you can just add a Border to the label to get your desired padding.

Answer (score 1):

To defer centering until rendering, I like this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244157) due to [finnw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12048/finnw), where `this` is a suitable component:

```
private BufferedImage image;
....
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.translate(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);
    g2d.translate(-image.getWidth() / 2, -image.getHeight() / 2);
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```