# How to find out whether an affine transformed rectangle contains a certain point, in Java?

Tags: java, coordinates, mouseevent, affinetransform

I'm trying to make an interactive GUI but I need to move a certain object whenever that rectangle is clicked + dragged. Basically I wanna know whether a rectangle, that has been affine transformed, contains a specific point (x, y). Is there a way to do this? I have tried using `contains()` method but it doesn't work for a rectangle that has been affine transformed. I checked the Java tutorials but the user interactive GUIs don't use affine transformation. Can someone point me to a tutorial that allows the user to affine transform a certain shape as well as move the shape ONLY when the shape itself is clicked + dragged. If not, how can I approach this?

Thanks.

Comment: just map your point `(x, y)` through the same AffineTransform and them compare.

Comment: but the method will not work for an affinetransformed point too, right?

Answer (score 1):

This [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/point-in-polygon) shows that `contains()` works as expected on a transformed `Shape`. The [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/point-in-polygon) uses `Polygon`, but `Rectangle` also implements `Shape`.

If instead the graphics context itself is transformed, you'll have to create an inverse "to capture the changes you make to the transform", as shown this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244285).