# java2d and scale

Tags: java, java-2d

when I scale my shape [Rectangle] with `g2d.scale(2,2)` or with `AffineTransform` , I can't detect correct hit on shape because my shape scale still same as previous and only view of shape is change.

I need solution for solving this problem [change size of shape after Transform].

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an inverse transform, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244285), or do the scaling explicitly, as shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/scaledview).