# JComponent JPanel Zoom, pan and Coordinates Question

Tags: java, swing, zooming, affinetransform

I have a `JPanel` with an vector image that the user can zoom and pan on. Overlaying this image is a (transparent) `JComponent`, which I allow the user to annotate the underlying image.  This works great at full scale, but If I zoom in, using `AffineTransform`, the overlaying coordinates are affected also.  So, If a user draws a box on the image the box is scaled also.

Any suggestions on how to decouple this behaviour?  So that the `JComponent` is not affected by the `JPanel`'s `AffineTransform`?

Comment: Please post the source code if you want people to help you. You simply don't have enough information in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you need both a forward and inverse transform to translate between the two co-ordinate systems. In this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/scaledview), the scaling equations are explicit; in this [alternate approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244285), a second `AffineTransform` is used.