# Java Swing rotate and zoom

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I have a JPanel surrounded with JScrollPane. This JPanel is used to display an image. I need to provide functionality like zoomIn, zoomOut, clockwiseRotate and antiClockwiseRotate. All these functionalities are working fine individually. For zoom, I call scale of graphics object. It happens on top left to bottom right basis. For rotation, I reset the scale, and translate, rotate & translate back the graphics object. But when I combine zoom with rotate, it behaves differently. For instance, I rotate clockwise and the image gets rotated to 1.57079633 radians (approx 90 degree). Now when I press zoom, the image gets zoomed but the zooming happens based on top right  and bottom left basis instead of top left and bottom right basis. If I again rotate the image in clockwise direction, I reset the zoom, that is I scale the image to its original size and call translate, rotate and translate back on graphics object. Now if I press zoom again, it zooms in based on bottom right and top left basis.

Hence the problem is the Image's coordinates are not getting changed when panels coordinates are changed. Can somebody help me out in changing the coordinates of the image?

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{     
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate((tempWidth/2), (tempHeight/2));
    g2d.rotate(m_rotate);
    g2d.translate(-(tempWidth/2), -(tempHeight/2));
    g2d.scale(m_zoom, m_zoom); 
    if(this.image != null && this.image.getHeight(null) > 0)
    {
        g2d.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0,302,312,this);         
    } 
    else
    {
        g2d.drawString("View Image Here!. ", 20, 20);
    }    
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040502/zoom-panel-in-java-appliction/10040546#10040546

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
 2) Override `paintComponent()` in a `JPanel`, not `paint()` 3) `this.image.getHeight(null)` should be `this.image.getHeight(this)`

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4292509/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. It made me think in a new dimension which helped me to solve the issue. All I did is just scaling the image before rotating and it runs well now.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{          
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g; 
    g2d.scale(m_zoom, m_zoom);//This is what made the magic    
    g2d.translate((tempWidth/2), (tempHeight/2));     
    g2d.rotate(m_rotate);     
    g2d.translate(-(tempWidth/2), -(tempHeight/2)); 
    /*g2d.scale(m_zoom, m_zoom); removed this and placed above */
    if(this.image != null && this.image.getHeight(null) > 0)     
    {         
        g2d.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0,302,312,this);
    }
    else
    {         
        g2d.drawString("View Image Here!. ", 20, 20);
    }     
}
```