# Scaling and zoom

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I need to implement zoom for a `JDesktopPane` contained in a `JScrollPane`. I have had prior success zooming by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method and calling `scale(double,double)`.

This is not working properly: the `JInternalFrame`'s and `JPanel`'s scale as intended, but the `MouseListener`'s for the `JLabel`'s and such register at the pre-scaled locations. What can I do? Thank you for reading.

Comment: can't you scale the mouse coordinate too?

Comment: For a jlabel with a mouseListener, the mouseEntered(), mouseExited(),... all of its methods registers at the unscaled location. Doing some mouse coordinate scaling like mouseEvent.getX()/scaleFactor won't fix that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ScaledPanel`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/scaledview) shows how to scale mouse coordinates using explicit transformation methods: `scaleX`, `scaleY`, `unScaleX` and `unScaleY`. Alternatively, you can use an inverse transformation, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244157/reverse-java-graphics2d-scaled-and-rotated-coordinates/2244285#2244285).

Comment: I already knew how to scale mouse coordintes, that isn't the problem. but thanks anyways.

Comment: Ah, I see now: you're going to watch `mouseMoved()` and scale the coordinates in order to determine your own `mouseEntered()`.

Comment: There's a lot of moving pieces on screen, I was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to 'collision detection'. But ok, there's probably no better way.