# Angular displacement on canvas

Tags: math, formula

I have a square (100px x 100px) with origin at 0,0 (upper left).
When I move the mouse, lets say 10 pixel x and y, I move the origin according to displacement and then origin becomes 10,10, simple. Works fine!

When I rotate the square, my rotation function rotates it fine, but then, after the square is rotated, lets say 10 degrees, the origin point should be move accordingly to the rotation. And now, I have no idea of the formula I have to apply to make it append!

I wikipedia, but I tink it's too complicated.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_displacement

and

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine#Sine.2C_cosine.2C_and_tangent

Example: After a 90 deg rotation to the left, the origin is now at : lower left, now when I move the mouse to to right, the picture go UP!!!!

Comment: I think this question may belong on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you looking to rotate the square around the center of it? If so, this forum post might help: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/532033-how-to-rotate-a-square-by-an-angle-image/

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the transform to convert a mouse position on the rotated square to the corresponding point on the original square?  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244157/reverse-java-graphics2d-scaled-and-rotated-coordinates) may be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a figure and you want to rotate it by angle `alpha` and translate it so that point `(cx, cy)` of the figure gets to point `(sx, sy)` after the transformation.

[image]

The transformation is

```
transformed_x = x*cos(alpha) - y*sin(alpha) + offset_x
transformed_y = x*sin(alpha) + y*cos(alpha) + offset_y
```

to compute desired `offset_x` and `offset_y` values you just need to put your requirement about `(cx, cy)` and `(sx, sy)` into the above equations:

```
sx = cx*cos(alpha) - cy*sin(alpha) + offset_x
sy = cx*sin(alpha) + cy*cos(alpha) + offset_y
```

and now you can easily extract the offset values from that:

```
offset_x = sx - cx*cos(alpha) + cy*sin(alpha)
offset_y = sy - cx*sin(alpha) - cy*cos(alpha)
```

To set up canvas transform for it you need just to call

```
context.translate(sx - cx*Math.cos(alpha) + cy*Math.sin(alpha),
                  sy - cx*Math.sin(alpha) - cy*Math.cos(alpha));
context.rotate(alpha);
```

You can see a little demo of this formula [following this link](http://raksy.dyndns.org/ctest.html).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are applying an offset to the rectangle points based on your mouse position, then rotating the resulting points about the origin.

Instead, try applying your mouse offset *after* you do your rotation, not before.

Comment: obvious answer, that don't make the cut, but i have try very hard to make it work... no luck !