# can't get my coordinates graphics2D mouseclick java

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, affinetransform

I got an extended `JLabel` class where I draw my Map using the code below :
the `new AffineTransform()` is the identity to left my image as it is (0,0,w,h)

```
 mygraphics2D = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
 graphics2D.scale(2.0,2.0) ;
 graphics2D.rotate(....
 graphics2D.drawImage(myImageIcon.getImage(),new AffineTransform(), this);
```

now when I click on my `JLabel` using this event :

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
x =e.getX() ;
y = e.getY();
NewX = ????
NewY = ????
}
```

I want to retrieve my new coordinates "the scaled,rotated ... coords" I tried

```
Point2D ptSrc = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
Point2D ptDst = new Point2D.Double(0, 0);
mygraphics2D.getTransform().transform(ptSrc, ptDst);
```

but the ptDst is different from the (scaled,rotated,..) coordinates, any help please !!!

Comment: *I want to retrieve my new coordinates "the scaled,rotated ... coords"*  Why?  What relevance are they, or the scaling/rotation?  What is the feature this is supposed to implement?

Comment: I have a map that can be transformed (scale, rotates, translate), & I want to add objects by clicking on the `JLabel` so the new object will be located at the new coords

Comment: I think AndrewThompson is right.  Do you *really* need to apply the transform when you click or can you just let the paint process take care of it for you?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE.  Even as code snippets go, those are not very instructive.  *"I have a map that can be transformed (scale, rotates, translate)"* Since the image is not transformed in any way, it makes me wonder..   What part of the map **is** transformed?

Comment: my map is `myImageIcon.getImage()` when i scale for example the coords changes of course, when i click on a specific region of the image i want to add my object there

Comment: a) That was as clear as mud.  b) Now that two people have made comments, you need to prefix a comment with @MadProgrammer (or other name) to ensure the person is notified of the comment.

Comment: @SéddikLaraba Are you *sure* `ptDst` doesn't contain the scaled/rotated point?
`final Point transformed = graphics.getTransform().transform(e.getPoint(), null);`

Comment: may be i should use the inverted transformation @veer

Comment: @SéddikLaraba yes, sorry, I'm an idiot. I didn't quite realize what you were asking for :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need both a forward and inverse transform to translate between the two co-ordinate systems. In this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/scaledview), the scaling equations are explicit; in this [alternate approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244285), a second `AffineTransform` is used.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted, retrieve mouse coords from a scaled JPanel, I don't get why none understood that, even if its blod written ???,  thank you @trashgod

Comment: You're welcome. Credit to commenters for elucidation and to @finw for a working example; many references merely suggest that it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Its not so hard ;-)

1. When you repaint the Component save the `AffineTransform` after the transforming with `g2.getTransform()`
2. Then call the function `invert()` on it
3. In the `mouseClicked()` event us the following code:

   ```
   Point2D p= trans.transform(new Point2D.Double(evt.getX(), evt.getY()), null);
   System.out.println("click x="+p.getX()+" y="+p.getY());
   ```

Thats it!

Comment: Necro-whatever blah. This answer is still relevant in 2022! THANK YOU. I was having issues with the mouse after using affineTransform and couldn't get inverseTransform to work. The way you do it here pointed me in the right direction. Now inverseTransform in the mouseMoved method works perfectly. (It is advised to create the Point2D during initiation, then use setLocation to update it instead of creating a potential memory leak by creating a new Point2D during every mouse click or move event.)

Answer (score 1):

I found these:

- http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19387.html
- http://www.java.net/node/685054

Don't know if they will help or not.