# Trigger MouseListener when pressing on my JComponent, even if it is transformed by an AffineTransform

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, mouselistener, affinetransform

I am trying to add a MouseListener to my custom JComponent. I just want the MouseListener to be triggered when pressing withing the bounds of the circle (the JComponent's painting method draws a circle). I have tried with the below code but I just cannot get it to work (loook especially in the `mousePressed` method).  How can I tackle this problem?

The SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class AffineTransformTest {

    private static TransformingCanvas canvas;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        canvas = new AffineTransformTest.TransformingCanvas();
        TranslateHandler translater = new TranslateHandler();
        canvas.addMouseListener(translater);
        canvas.addMouseMotionListener(translater);
        canvas.addMouseWheelListener(new ScaleHandler());
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class TransformingCanvas extends JComponent {

        private double translateX;
        private double translateY;
        private double scale;

        TransformingCanvas() {
            translateX = 0;
            translateY = 0;
            scale = 1;
            setOpaque(true);
            setDoubleBuffered(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
            tx.translate(translateX, translateY);
            tx.scale(scale, scale);
            Graphics2D ourGraphics = (Graphics2D) g;
            ourGraphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            ourGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            ourGraphics.setTransform(tx);
            ourGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            ourGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            ourGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            ourGraphics.fillOval(50, 50, 50, 50);
        }
    }

    private static class TranslateHandler implements MouseListener,
            MouseMotionListener {

        private int lastOffsetX;
        private int lastOffsetY;

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            lastOffsetX = e.getX();
            lastOffsetY = e.getY();

            double width = canvas.scale * 50;
            double height = canvas.scale * 50;
            double x = (AffineTransformTest.canvas.getWidth() - width) / 2;
            double y = (AffineTransformTest.canvas.getHeight() - height) / 2;
            Rectangle2D.Double bounds = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
            System.out.println(bounds + " " + e.getPoint());
            if (bounds.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                System.out.println("Click!");
            }
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            int newX = e.getX() - lastOffsetX;
            int newY = e.getY() - lastOffsetY;

            lastOffsetX += newX;
            lastOffsetY += newY;

            canvas.translateX += newX;
            canvas.translateY += newY;

            canvas.repaint();
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    }

    private static class ScaleHandler implements MouseWheelListener {

        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            if (e.getScrollType() == MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL) {
                canvas.scale += (.1 * e.getWheelRotation());
                canvas.scale = Math.max(0.00001, canvas.scale);
                canvas.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better to extend `JButton` than `JComponent` for the specific situation & BTW what do you mean by *"cannot get it to work"*

Comment: Maybe, but this is just a SSCCE. My real code is much bigger and is using custom components derived from JComponent, so I thought this code would match my real problem better.

Comment: What doesn't work is when you zoom in and out. The mouse presses are never within the bounds of the painted object when you have zoomed in or out.

Comment: Two approaches are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11821838/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code. Some quick notes, there is still some debug in the code, and replace calls to LOGGER object with System.out.println().

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;


public abstract class LCARSComponent extends JComponent implements MouseInputListener {

/**
 * A reference to the global Logger object.
 */
protected final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);

protected int x;
protected int y;
protected int w;
protected int h;

protected double scaleFactor = 1.0;

protected Area area;
protected Area scaledArea;
protected int style;

protected Color color;

protected AffineTransform renderingTransform;

protected ActionListener actionListener;

public LCARSComponent(Container parent, int x, int y, int w, int h, int style) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;

    this.style = style;

    setBounds(x,y,w,h);

    addMouseListener(this);

}


@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    /**
     * First, paint the background if the component is opaque. Required when 
     * JComponent is extended, and the paintCompnent() method is overridden.
     */
    if(isOpaque()) {
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    /**
     * Create a Graphics2D object so we can use Java 2D features.
     */
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    /**
     * Set the anti aliasing rendering hint and the color to draw with.
     */
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setColor(color);


    scaleComponent();       

    /**
     * Draw the Area object of the LCARS component, and fill it.
     */
    g2d.draw(scaledArea);
    g2d.fill(scaledArea);

    g2d.drawRect(scaledArea.getBounds().x, scaledArea.getBounds().y, scaledArea.getBounds().width, scaledArea.getBounds().height);

    /**
     * Clean up when the method has completed by disposing the Graphics2D object that was created.
     */
    g2d.dispose();

}


protected void scaleComponent() {
    double sw = (double)getParent().getWidth() / (double)getParent().getPreferredSize().width;
    double sh = (double)getParent().getHeight() / (double)getParent().getPreferredSize().height;

    LOGGER.info("scaledWidth = " + sw);
    LOGGER.info("scaledHeight = " + sh);

    double scaleFactor;

    if(sh < sw) {
        scaleFactor = sh;
    }
    else {
        scaleFactor = sw;
    }

    LOGGER.info("scaleFactor = " + scaleFactor);

    if(scaleFactor != this.scaleFactor) {
        this.scaleFactor = scaleFactor;

        scaledArea = new Area(area);
        renderingTransform = new AffineTransform();
        renderingTransform.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        scaledArea.transform(renderingTransform);           
    }

    setBounds((int)(this.x*scaleFactor), (int)(this.y*scaleFactor), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
}


public Point screenToComponent(Point pt) {

    if(renderingTransform == null) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)(this.getParent().getGraphics());
        renderingTransform = g2d.getTransform();            
    }


    Point2D pt2d = renderingTransform.transform(pt,null);

    LOGGER.info("mouse click: " + pt.getX() + ", " + pt.getY() + "  --  " + pt2d.getX() + ", " + pt2d.getY());
    return new Point((int)Math.round(pt2d.getX()), (int)Math.round(pt2d.getY()));
}


public void setActionListener(ActionListener actionListener) {
    this.actionListener = actionListener;
}


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    Point pt = e.getPoint();
    LOGGER.info("mouseClicked: " + this.getName() + " - " + pt.getX() + ", " + pt.getY());

    if(area.contains(e.getPoint())) {

        if(actionListener != null) {
            actionListener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(e.getSource(), e.getID(), e.paramString()));
        }

        if(color.equals(Color.black))
            color = Color.blue;
        else
            color = Color.black;
        this.repaint();
    }
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(area.contains(e.getLocationOnScreen()))
        System.out.println("mousePressed()...");
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(area.contains(e.getLocationOnScreen()))
        System.out.println("mouseReleased()...");
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    Point pt = e.getPoint();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println("mouseEntered()...");
    LOGGER.info("mouseEntered: " + this.getName() + " - " + pt.getX() + ", " + pt.getY());

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Point pt = e.getPoint();
    System.out.println("mouseExited()...");
    LOGGER.info("mouseExited: " + pt.getX() + ", " + pt.getY());
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("mouseDragged()...");
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("mouseMoved()...");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

First, I would use a Shape or Area object and use its .contains() method. Bounds is always a Rectangle that surrounds your entire shape. Also, not sure why you are creating a bounds rectangle when you can simply use the setBounds() method of your JComponent.

Second, the bounds of a JComponent can be translated, but I haven't found anything built-in to scale them. Though, you can change the size dynamically. I am working on an identical problem. Right now I am considering dynamically changing the bounds when my JComponent scales. I am trying to understand correlation between screen coordinates and JComponent coordinates. The mouse coordinates always seem to be in unscaled frame/screen coordinates (might be an artifact of the full screen mode I am using. The solutions I have seen paint everything in a JPanel and do not use discrete JComponents to solve the scaling problem. The code is a little hard to follow, and not particularly modular, but it does work.

In any case, I am sure it can ultimately be done. It is simply a matter of getting the math right. I will post the code for the scalable JComponent extension when I have finished it and it works reliably. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Okay, here is the code for an abstract class that extends JComponent and allows you to scale and translate the component and still click on it reliably. Not complete yet, but it illustrates how to extend JComponent and have the it be scalable and clickable. To use extend and have your extension create an Area object. Note that I did not make it arbitrarily scalable. It scales based on screen size, which was my requirement.