# How to detect mouse over on drawn image with awt.Graphics.drawImage() when transformed

Tags: java, swing

In a Java Swing panel I draw an image with arbitrary transfomation e.g.:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);
    AffineTransform rotateInstance AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotX, rotY);           
    transform.concatenate(rotateInstance);

    g.setTransform(transform);    
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0 , null);
}
```

What is the best way to detect mouse over on such an image?

Even better: the best way to detect mouse over only on non-transparent pixels?

Answer (score 1):

Construct a [`Shape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) that encloses the image, and use the [`AffineTransform`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) method `createTransformedShape()` to rotate the `Shape` along with the image. The `Shape` method `contains()` will allow for position testing in `Component` relative coordinates. Complete examples are seen [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/point-in-polygon) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594424/230513). Two approaches to inverse coordinate transformation are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11821838/230513).

[image]